# How to get nmap to show ftp banner / welcome message?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, nmap

What are the commands to get nmap to show ftp banner responses?

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
nmap -sV --script=banner <target>
```

will connect to open TCP ports and and print anything sent in response within the first 5 seconds. More details (and in case you don't have the script, you can download it here) at [banner NSE script | nmap.org](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/banner.html).

You can further filter which port to use, eg. FTP, with `-p 21`.

Comment: If all you want is the banner, `-sV` is unnecessary.

Comment: when I do that command I get: Failed to resolve/decode supposed IPv4 source address "v": No address associated with hostname. Also I cant seem to open my list with the -iL list6.txt command.